# Basic algebraic structures

Tags: group-theory

On the wikipedia article about Quazigroups, there is a nice matrix chart of Group axioms and the structures that match a combination.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup

Yet, i've noticed some combinations missing, they are:

- only Identity
- only Invertibility
- Identity and Invertibility
- Associativity and Invertibility
- Totality and Identity

My question is - **do such structures exist ? if yes - what are their names ?**

p.s.: No mention of such primitive structures exists in related question [Algebraic structure cheat sheet anyone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12646/18257)

and neither on larger wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures

Comment: You cannot have *invertibility* without *identity*. The definition of the first requires the other.

Comment: ok -
that should be "Magma with Identity" and such structure is called `unital magma`, per related question. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2089449/18257

Comment: @freakish - but Quazigroup has Totality + Invertibility without having Identity ?